# Javascript Menu Accordion Don't word

Tags: javascript, html, css, tailwind-css

I am a beginner in programming, and I am trying to create a FAQ for my portfolio site.

I'm using the tailwind css framework and I'm not getting accordion with javascript, could you help me?

I have the class accordion__item when clicked on the element, I want it to show the content contained in the accordion__content paragraph element, and when clicked again, that it closes the content. Can you help me?

```js
let item = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion__item");
let i;

for (i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
  item[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("open");
  });
}
```

```css
.open {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
  <script src="./modal.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <section class="bg-white dark:bg-gray-900">
    <div class="container max-w-4xl px-6 py-10 mx-auto">
      <h1 class="text-4xl font-semibold text-center text-gray-800 dark:text-white">Frequently asked questions</h1>

      <div class="mt-12 space-y-8">
        <div class="border-2 border-gray-100 rounded-lg dark:border-gray-700 accordion__item open">
          <button class="flex items-center justify-between w-full p-8">
                            <h1 class="font-semibold text-gray-700 dark:text-white">How i can play for my appoinment ?</h1>
    
                            <span class="text-gray-400 bg-gray-200 rounded-full">
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="w-6 h-6" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M18 12H6" />
                                </svg>
                            </span>
                        </button>

          <hr class="border-gray-200 dark:border-gray-700">

          <p class="p-8 text-sm text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-300 accordion__content">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas eaque nobis, fugit odit omnis fugiat deleniti animi ab maxime cum laboriosam recusandae facere dolorum veniam quia pariatur obcaecati illo ducimus?
          </p>
        </div>




      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you are toggling `display: block`. Initially elements are either `block` or `inline` based on their nature.
Next thing is that you are toggling it on the container which contains the toggle button as well.

To fix it we need to toggle the `display: none` which is actually hiding elements and move the class toggle target from the container to its content.

```js
let item = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion__item");
let i;

for (i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
  item[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.querySelector('.accordion__content').classList.toggle("d-none");
  });
}
```

```css
.open {
  display: block
}

.d-none {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
  <script src="./modal.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <section class="bg-white dark:bg-gray-900">
    <div class="container max-w-4xl px-6 py-10 mx-auto">
      <h1 class="text-4xl font-semibold text-center text-gray-800 dark:text-white">Frequently asked questions</h1>

      <div class="mt-12 space-y-8">
        <div class="border-2 border-gray-100 rounded-lg dark:border-gray-700 accordion__item open">
          <button class="flex items-center justify-between w-full p-8">
                            <h1 class="font-semibold text-gray-700 dark:text-white">How i can play for my appoinment ?</h1>
    
                            <span class="text-gray-400 bg-gray-200 rounded-full">
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="w-6 h-6" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M18 12H6" />
                                </svg>
                            </span>
                        </button>

          <hr class="border-gray-200 dark:border-gray-700">

          <p class="p-8 text-sm text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-300 accordion__content">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas eaque nobis, fugit odit omnis fugiat deleniti animi ab maxime cum laboriosam recusandae facere dolorum veniam quia pariatur obcaecati illo ducimus?
          </p>
        </div>




      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

Comment: Hello @Sergey

First of all, thank you very much for your response. Segey, can you tell me why your code works here in the stackoverflow snippet, and in my code it doesn't? I just made these changes, and nothing happens in my code, is it a tailwind problem? I am creating a simple static site, where I just import the cdn directly into my html, would that be a problem? If you can help me, thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry, it was a problem in my javascript. Thanks, your answer solved my problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

So in this situation, the "accordion__content" should be `display: none` always. Then you can check for the open class and turn accordion__content into `display: block`.

```
.accordion__content {
  display: none;
}

.open .accordion__content {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Shadow
Thank you for your input, your answer is also correct, but I used sergey's solution below and it worked for my problem. thank you very much.